# How to send a text from Android device to a computer

Tags: android, message, send

We have a requirement wherein we want to send some text message from android powered device to a server in PC, when this message is recieved it will trigger some action in PC? How do I configure my device to listen to that server and are there any third party server which I need to use. I tried using one of our in-house servers to communicate from device to PC but not able to achieve. If anyone has achieved the same using any third party servers please share your comments and also any other settings which needs to be done in device.

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking for is to install some sort of client on the PC that can communicate with an Android app then there are a bunch of existing software packages such as what [RemoteDroid](http://www.remotedroid.net/) offers. You can checkout the source code at http://code.google.com/p/remotedroid/source/checkout.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about only sending message from device to server then you can use http / tcp. If your server is in VPN then you may need take care of that. If you are looking for other way also (server to device) you can use cloud to device messaging.